# Foreach loop gives error message: task 1 failed - "cannot use this function"

Tags: raster, r

I have maximum daily temperature data (raster format) from [E-OBS](https://surfobs.climate.copernicus.eu/dataaccess/access_eobs_chunks.php) for the period 1980-2019. I have reduced this to 1985-2014 and only kept the months April-October (30 years, 214 days). Now I want to calculate a 90th percentile rasterlayer for each day from 1st May until 30th September (153 days). So for each day calculate the 90th percentile across the 30 years and with a 15-day centered window.

I have called the rasterstack RP:

```
RP <- setZ(RP, as.Date(names(RP), format = "X%Y.%m.%d")) # Set the time dimension using the rasterlayer names
RP <- subset(RP, which(getZ(RP) >= '1985-01-01' & (getZ(RP) <= '2014-12-31'))) # Keep only 1985-2014
RP <- subset(RP, which(substr(getZ(RP),6,7) %in% c('04','05','06','07','08','09','10'))) # Keep only April-October
```

I have used a foreach loop, because the for loop took too much time.

```
P90 <- stack() # Create empty rasterstack for the 90th percentile layers

registerDoParallel(makeCluster(detectCores()-1))

P90 <- foreach (d = 1:153, .packages = "raster", .combine = addLayer, .init = P90, .inorder = TRUE) %dopar% {
  Raster_1 <- stack() # Create empty rasterstack to store all the layers needed for the calculation (30 years x 15 days = 450 layers)
  
  for (i in 0:29) { # Calculation is done for all 30 years
    
    for (j in -7:7) { # Moving window of 15 days is used, 7 days before and 7 days after the chosen day
      Raster_1 <- addLayer(Raster_1, RP[[30 + d + i*214 + j]])
    }
  }
  
  P90 <<- addLayer(P90, calc(x = Raster_1, fun = function(x) quantile(x, probs = c(0.90), na.rm = TRUE)), forceapply = TRUE) # 90th percentile calculation
}

stopCluster()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "cannot use this function"
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

The strange thing is also, using the exact same code on a different dataset (not from E-OBS, but from the ESGF data portal) the code works perfectly fine and I receive a P90 rasterstack with 153 layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works. The problem was not in the foreach loop but in the quantile calculation itself.

The following code gives me exactly what I needed:

```
P90 <- stack() # Create empty rasterstack for the 90th percentile layers

registerDoParallel(makeCluster(detectCores()-1))

P90 <- foreach (d = 1:153, .packages = "raster", .combine = addLayer, .init = P90, .inorder = TRUE) %dopar% {
  Raster_1 <- stack() # Create empty rasterstack to store all the layers needed for the calculation (30 years x 15 days = 450 layers)
  
  for (i in 0:29) { # Calculation is done for the 30 years of the reference period
    
    for (j in -7:7) { # Moving window of 15 days is used, 7 days before and 7 days after the chosen day
      Raster_1 <- addLayer(Raster_1, RP[[30 + d + i*214 + j]])
    }
  }
  
  Q90 <- function(x) {quantile(x, probs = 0.90, na.rm = TRUE)}
  P90 <<- addLayer(P90, calc(Raster_1, Q90)) 

}
stopCluster()
```